# Printer settings can no longer be changed since updating to Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: printing, 15.10

Just updated to Ubuntu 15.10 and using Libre Office 5 I find that I can no longer change paper settings when I want to print. I go to File>Printer Settings>Properties and the paper size and orientation are not high-lighted for changing.

Comment: I had noticed this before, but I think it's a bug in Libre - did it work prior to 15.10?

Comment: Yes it did. Then I updated to 15.10 giving me Libre 5.

Comment: I tried to open a bur report at Libre, but I'm not sure it worked.  I'm not terribly facile at such things, perhaps you could also try?